# Linux copy command

Tags: command-line

For example I have two users A and B. User A has admin privileges.

I am logged in as B and I want to know how can I copy `/etc/sudoers` to the home directory of B using a single command and after `/etc/sudoers` is copied, it must be owned by user B by default, without using `chmod` or `chown`.

Comment: You could always write a script that does both for you?

Comment: Or a sequence && of || commands ; to copy stuff

Comment: I mean that I gave B user admin privileges, then I am able to copy /etc/sudoers in B home dir, but when I type ls -alh to see who owns the directory it says root. So, what I am trying to do is to copy /etc/sudoers in B home dir and B must be the owner without using chown or other permission directives

Comment: Am I clear what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess e.g.

```
sudo cat /etc/sudoers > ~/sudoers
```

as user B would do what you want. This will in practice copy a file readable via `sudo` privileges and leave B as owner.

[Why you would want to do this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) is still a bit unclear though. Perhaps some other answer would fit better if we knew the circumstances. Why not just use `chown`? Is it a theoretical school assignment?

Comment: Thanks. I never thought about this. Seems a good solution. I am doing some research in my free time on alternative solutions to some linux commands.